# How to create a single segment stream in Pravega?

Tags: rust

In the [pravega-client-rust](https://github.com/pravega/pravega-client-rust), a `ByteWriter` requires a single segment stream as per a comment in the docs:

```
// assuming scope:myscope, stream:mystream exist.
// notice that this stream should be a fixed sized single segment stream
let stream = ScopedStream::from("myscope/mystream");
```

I can see in `pravega-admin` that after creating a scope and a stream using `pravega-cli`, I have 4 segments:

```
> controller describe-stream my-scope my-stream
Successful REST request.
{
  "scopeName": "my-scope",
  "streamName": "my-stream",
  "scalingPolicy": {
    "type": "FIXED_NUM_SEGMENTS",
    "minSegments": 4
  },
  "tags": [],
  "timestampAggregationTimeout": 0,
  "rolloverSizeBytes": 0
}
```

I cannot find anywhere in the docs or examples, either for the Rust client or Pravega generally, how to set the segment count to 1. How can this be done, ideally using `pravega-admin` CLI?

Comment: Only tenuously Rust, but I couldn't see a Pravega tag and I don't have sufficient points to create new tags.

Comment: So you're asking how to configure this software? If so that's not a programming question though and as such completely off-topic on SO.